# Prefix a string in each item of a array in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an array like below:

```
 var arrItems = [
  {id: '1', value: 'table', price: 100},
  {id: '2', value: 'chair', price: 200},
  {id: '3', value: 'bed', price: 300},
];
```

How to prefix a string 'AB' in each item's id in the array?
My result array should be :

```
 var arrItems = [
      {id: 'AB1', value: 'table', price: 100},
      {id: 'AB2', value: 'chair', price: 200},
      {id: 'AB3', value: 'bed', price: 300},
    ];
```

Can I achieve it using the Javascript in map function?

Comment: Have you made any attempt at all yourself so far? You're on the right track, you can use `.map` (or `forEach` if you want to mutate), but try writing some code first

Comment: `arrItems` holds an array and not JSON. JSON ist a string based representation of data.

Comment: WHY do you want to change ids? Shouldn't these things be unique and static, from the moment you generate them untill the end of time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

I also used the [Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to copy object of collection and for easy property change.

```js
var arrItems = [
  {id: '1', value: 'table', price: 100},
  {id: '2', value: 'chair', price: 200},
  {id: '3', value: 'bed', price: 300},
];

var result = arrItems.map(i => ({...i, id: 'AB' + i.id }))

console.log(result)
```

Comment: While you've supplied a working answer, you haven't explained any of it. You haven't provided any links to related resources for further research, no explanations of what your solution entails, or comments in the code.

Comment: I fixed my mistakes

Comment: Thanks, it fixed my issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through the array and change the of each object in that array:

```js
var arrItems = [
  {id: '1', value: 'table', price: 100},
  {id: '2', value: 'chair', price: 200},
  {id: '3', value: 'bed', price: 300},
];
// loop through the array and concatenate 'AB' to the id of each object in that array
arrItems.forEach(function(el) {
  el.id = 'AB' + el.id;
});
// just for the demo purpose, we'll log the array in the console
var output = 'Result:\n';
arrItems.forEach(function(el) {
  output += 'id: ' + el.id + ', value: ' + el.value + ', price: ' + el.price +'\n';
});
console.log(output);
```

Hope I pushed you further.